# Mockito test not working

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and while unit testing i am getting a null pointer exception. Can someone please let me know what am i doing wrong here? Below is the service method which needs to be tested:

```
    class a{
     public List<String> getabc(String div){
     ResponseEntity<SD> sd = resttemplate.getforEntity("http://localhost:8080/abc/"+div,SD.class);
     if(sd !=NULL && sd.getstatuscode() == HTTPstatus.oK){
     return sd.getbody().getsd();
     }
     }
```

---

```
    Public class testa{
     @Mock
     Resttemplate resttemplate;//mocking resttemplate

     @InjectMocks
     private a a1= new a(restTemplate); //injectingmocks to the service

     @Test
     public void testmetha(){
     List<String> ts = new ArrayList<>();
     ts.add("t1");
     ts.add("t2");
     SD sd = new SD();
      sd.setid(ts);
     ResponseEntity<SD> rs = new ResponseEntity<SD>(sd, HTTPSTATUS.OK);
     when(resttemplate.getforEntity("http://localhost:8080/abc/25",SD.class)).thenReturn(rs);
     ts = a1.getabc("25");
     assertEquals(3, a1.getabc("25").size());
     }
     }
```

It gives a null pointer exception at -  ts = a1.getabc("25");

Comment: Are you sure the exception isn't on the line above?  That would happen if you weren't using either the Mockito JUnit Runner or the Mockito JUnit rule.

Comment: yes sure its happening on this line only.

Comment: Please post the whole null pointer exception. In your code it's virtually impossible that the NPE is exactly in that line, to me it looks like it might be inside the class `a`. And btw, class names should start with upper case, so it would be `A`, which is still a bad name for a class.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the instance creation from:

```
@InjectMocks
private a a1= new a(restTemplate); //injectingmocks to the service
```

it should be:

```
@InjectMocks
private a a1;
```

Mockito will automatically detect your constructor and inject a mocks to build your object. Otherwise it may not work correctly.

Moreover make sure that your mocks are properly initialized, use a proper runner for test class `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or do it with @Before code.

```
@Before 
public void initMocks() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: `@InjectMocks` should work just fine with a given instance. It only prevents Mockito from using *constructor injection* (see the JavaDocs for that). Your second observation is much more likely to be the reason for the problems.

Comment: While you CAN use `@InjectMocks` with an Instance, in your example, resttemplate will still be null when your instance is created (because `@Mock` values are initialized loooooong after the variables have been created). I suggest following @staszko032 advice there.